# Triggering button with URL parameter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

As the title says, I need to trigger a certain button on ASP.net web form by using URL parameter. I figured out how to fill textboxes with parameters, but can't seem to find a solution for triggering a button. Any help is appreciated.

Button example:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Calculate" 
        onclick="Button2_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight-forward...All you have to do is call the "Button2_Click" method.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use javascript for this purpose.

```
    function triggerClick()
{
var btnSubmitTags = document.getElementById("YourButtonIdHere");
btnSubmitTags.click();
}
```

You can call this function at the onLoad of body tag like this

```
<body onload="triggerClick()">
```

Or like this

```
window.onload = function()
                {
                   triggerClick();
                };
```

You can also populate your textboxes with the values from queryStrings

But I don't know why you need to trigger the button using querystring. Please make it clear if you didn't meant this.

Comment: Basically I need to fill two textboxes and trigger a button using HTTP GET method. So I assume i need to pass the textbox values and trigger a button(call method) with parameters in URL.

Comment: You can make the button click using this javascript code. Also the textboxes can be prepopulated from the params in the queryString.